# What is the correct way to install memcached

Tags: php, windows, memcached

Here is my config:

Wamp server 3, 64bit

OS: windows 10

PHP: 7.1.11

What is the correct way and how to install memcache**d**?

Comment: Google point me to this page (https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows) on my request memcached windows. Have you check it? You also can fall for docker image.

Comment: These packages work only php5.6. I found this: https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll
I tried many dlls, but did'nt work. Php error log: Not a Win32 application. Or
A specified module could not be found. (but the module is the right place)

Comment: again... you can use docker (with a prebuild images) this is what I do...

Comment: I do not want to use the docker. Other options?